# How do I dynamically load jquery into ie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer

I am trying to load a jquery file using getScript function in jquery. In both Chrome and firefox, it works. But only ie, it has nothing but a blank page showing to me. The getScript function is used within after an ajax call and to add interactivity to the loaded content of this ajax call.

Is there a way I can follow to dynamically load jquery file when I am working with internet explorer?

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="restaurant.css"></link>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="restaurant.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="banner"></div>
    <div id="cart"></div>
    <ul id="headbar">
        <li id="aboutButton">About</li>
        <li id="menuButton">Our Menus</li>
        <li id="directionhoursButton">Direction&Hours</li>
        <li id="orderButton">Orders</li>
        <li id="reviewsButton">Reviews</li>
        <li id="contactsButton">Contacts</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="display"></div>
</body>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#aboutButton').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'about-ajax-return.php',
            dataType:'html',
            cache:true,
            success: function(data, textStatus){
                $('#display').html(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                $('#display').html("<p class='error'>Unable to retrieve information. Status: " + textStatus + "  Error: " + errorThrown + "</p>");
            }
        });
    });
    $('#menuButton').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'menu-ajax-return.php',
            dataType:'html',
            cache:true,
            success: function(data, textStatus){
                $('#display').html(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                $('#display').html("<p class='error'>Unable to retrieve information. Status: " + textStatus + "  Error: " + errorThrown + "</p>");
            }
        });
        $('head').append('<link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu-ajax-return.css"></link>');
        $.getScript("menu-ajax-return.js");
    });});
```

below is menu-ajax-return.js which I try to load by using getScript

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#buttonPizza').click(function(){
        $('.sandwiches')
            .css("display", "none");
        $('.pasta')
            .css("display", "none");
        $('.pizza')
            .css("display", "inline");  
    });
    $('#buttonSandwiches').click(function(){
        $('.sandwiches')
            .css("display", "initial");
        $('.pasta')
            .css("display", "none");
        $('.pizza')
            .css("display", "none");    
    });
    $('#buttonPasta').click(function(){
        $('.sandwiches')
            .css("display", "none");
        $('.pasta')
            .css("display", "initial");
        $('.pizza')
            .css("display", "none");    
    });

    $('#buttonPizza').trigger("click");
});

    <div id="nav">
    <ul class="menuPage" id="foodTypeMenu">
        <li id="buttonPizza">Pizzas!</li>
        <li id="buttonSandwiches">Sandwiches & Paninis</li>
        <li id="buttonPasta">Pastas</li>
        <li id="buttonEntrees">Entr&eacute;es</li>
        <li id="buttonAppetizer">Appetizers</li>
        <li id="buttonWrap">Wraps</li>
        <li id="buttonSoupSalad">Soup & Salad</li>
        <li id="buttonSideorder">Side Orders</li>
        <li id="buttonDesert">Deserts</li>
        <li id="buttonSpecialities">House Specialities</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no general reason why that wouldn't work in IE, so you have to show the specific code that you are using to get help with it.

Comment: Is your website running local or online?? This could be security settings in your browser. Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: What version of IE and jQuery are you using?